# Render stylesheet inside script tag

Tags: javascript, css

I have a requirement where depending on a condition I need to render a stylesheet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var isWelcomePage = window.location.pathname.match(/^\welcome/);
 if(isWelcomePage){
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="welcome.css"/>
 }
</script>
```

Is this possible? or is there any better way?

Comment: It is absolutely possible but why? Do you have a server side language you can utilize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this

HTML

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" id="updatable-css" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var isWelcomePage = window.location.pathname.match(/^\welcome/);
 if(isWelcomePage){
   document.getElementById('updatable-css').href = "welcome.css";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `link` tag dynamically, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var isWelcomePage = window.location.pathname.match(/^\welcome/);
 if(isWelcomePage) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.href = 'welcome.css';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';

    document.head.appendChild(link);
 }
</script>
```